# Binding the "onselect" event to a function, that handles the maximum chars. inside an input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a function to limit the number of chars. a user is allowed to type inside an input text field.

This is it:

```
$.fn.restringLength = function (id, maxLen) {

            $(id).keypress(function(e){

                var kCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which,

                    len = $(id).val().length;

                if (kCode != 8 && kCode != 46) {

                    if (len > maxLen) e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
```

The function binds the keypress event and gets the code of the pushed key.

If the char. limit is reached, it allows only the delete and backspace keys to be pushed.

What it needs to work great, is a way to bind the "onselect" event in order to have the following behavior:

**when the user selects the whole text with the mouse, and types a letter or a number, the whole text gets deleted and that letter appears.**

This is something that most of us do when we want to replace some text with another, and I'd like my function to enable this.

Any ideas how?

Comment: What about just `<input type="text" maxlength="10" />`

Comment: @adeneo - never used it, is it cross browser? IE8 and maybe lower?

Comment: On an input, it should work everywhere, on a textarea, there are issues in older browsers.

Comment: Can you please write an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: If you decided to just use the maxlength attribute, or if you found something else that works, just post an answer yourself describing what you did, and what worked for you, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i may add something,

Your solution use keypress event, so the event is triggered **before** the new value of input is computed. That's why you have to check for special key like *backspace , enter* ... theses do not just add a character to the string so they require special treatment.

For this kind of processing, it's more convinient to have the handler triggered **after** the string computation. In that way, you can access the input value and modify it if it's not correct.

Unfortunately jquery does not support this event but you can use it with vanilla javascript method.

```
$(id)[0]   // get the vanilla js element
.oninput = function(e){
  this.value = this.value.substr( 0 , 10 )  // this.value contain the string after the key press processing
}
```